# System for automatically logging exact file code changes by line item

Tags: version-control

Does anyone know of a software or system for automatically tracking and logging exact line code changes into a log file?

For example, lets say I edit 7 files on Jan 16th, and I add and modify several lines of code in each file.

Is there a software or tool of any kind that would automagically know what edits I made, what was changed, and log the details in date order line-item file?

I am guessing something exists like this, but I cannot find out what I should be searching for. I looked at SVN and some other similar, but didn't get these capabilities from the descriptions I read.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that would **automagically** know this. This sort of information is easy to come by as a side-effect of using virtually any version control system though. It sounds like you're not using any VCS, you should start doing so now. SVN is a good option to start with.